# How can I get a result from a WebService to display on Android activity?

Tags: java, android, web-services, jakarta-ee, middleware

I have to create a Android application to make a Middleware because I have to question a big database.

This Middleware must be program in J2EE.

To learn how to a middleware interacts with an Android app, I wrote a little function named "ping" :

```
@GET
@Path("/echo/{input}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String ping(@PathParam("input") String input) {
    return input;
}
```

This function use the variable named "input" in the path, and display the content of it on a web page.

My problem is, above function works, I tested it on a classical browser and the function returned the String named "input" on the webpage. But now I want to question my Middleware with my Android App and display the content of "input" in my application activity.

So how can I get this String in my app ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the url used in the browser, from the android app.

From android you can call webservice using AsyncTask and HttpClient

To call the url

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet postRequest = new HttpGet("http://"+ip+":8080/echo/hello");
ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();           
String output= httpClient.execute(postRequest,handler);
httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Check whether your service is at port number 8080!